# Having trouble with double quotes in ReplacementText string for MSBuild FileUpdate target

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, msbuild

I have an issue figuring out how to escape double quotes properly in my MSBuild `FileUpdate` target, in the `ReplacementText` attribute.

What I'm trying to do is very simple.  I want to search for `AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")` and replace it with `AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.<revision number here>")`.  I'm using a `FileUpdate` element that looks like this:

```
<FileUpdate Files="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" Regex="AssemblyFileVersion(\(\x22)(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)" ReplacementText="AssemblyFileVersion$1$2.$3.$4.$(build_vcs_number_1)" />
```

This works fine, but it sure seems like a strange way to do it!  Basically, since I wasn't able to get double quotes to work in the `ReplacementText` attribute, I had to group the " from the Regex string, and then use the group number to insert the " into the `ReplacementText` (actually, I grouped the ( and the ", but I only needed to group the ").

I've tried all of the standard methods -- \", "", \x22, \x22, \", and nothing works.  I must be missing something obvious here, but what is it?

Embarrassed...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In *ML in quoted strings use `&quot;` to represent quotes.

For example:

```
<FileUpdate Files="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" Regex="(AssemblyFileVersion\(&quot;\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.)\d+(&quot;\))" ReplacementText="$1$(build_vcs_number_1)$2" />
```

You could probably also use single quotes instead, like so:

```
<FileUpdate Files="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" Regex='(AssemblyFileVersion\("\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.)\d+("\))' ReplacementText="$1$(build_vcs_number_1)$2" />
```

Comment: Thanks -- you have the strings backward, i.e. I'm having issues with ReplacementText, and not Regex.  The two strings behave quite differently, in terms of how they deal with escaped characters.  That said, I hadn't thought of &quot; or using ' instead of ", so I'll give that a try!  Great suggestion!

Comment: Oops, hang on a sec, I forgot to change an env. variable so the target didn't execute.  Stand by for another test!